# How to create a TypedQuery in JPQL that queries two tables using an implicit join?

Tags: java, rest, jpa, jpql, derby

I'm trying to learn how to use implicit joins in JPQL. An example I'm working from seems to suggest that one can reference a foreign key as a path and then have access to attributes in the table the foreign key references.

It's a 1:M mandatory relationship between User and Report.
userId is the foreign key that references User.

I've checked that I have the right libraries imported that I have the right mapping (@JoinColumn, @ManyToOne, @OneToMany, mappedBy, etc), everything seems to be okay.

```
@GET
@Path("findByTotalCalBurnedAndHeight/{height}/{totalCalBurned}")
@Produces({"application/json"})
public List<Report> findByTotalCalBurnedAndHeight(@PathParam("height") Integer height, @PathParam("totalCalBurned") Integer totalCalBurned) {
    TypedQuery<Report> q = em.createQuery("SELECT r FROM Report r WHERE r.totalCalBurned = :totalCalBurned AND r.userId.height = :height", Report.class);
    q.setParameter("height", height);
    q.setParameter("totalCalBurned", totalCalBurned);
    return q.getResultList();
}
```

As seen above I'm trying to access the "height" attribute in the "User" table with: r.UserId.height

Based on the example I'm working from I'd expect the join to work here however the result I'm getting is this error: "The state field path 'r.userId.height' cannot be resolved to a valid type."

Am I missing something here? Any feedback is much appreciated.

Update to show mapping:

In report class:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "REPORT_ID")
private Integer reportId;

@JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID", referencedColumnName = "USER_ID")
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Column(name = "USER_ID")
private Integer userId;
```

In user class:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "USER_ID")
private Integer userId;
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "userId")

@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Column(name = "HEIGHT")
private int height;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this part:

```
r.userId.height
```

In order for this to work, `userId` must be an entity. You can define a relationship with `user` field in `Report` and write something like:

```
"SELECT r FROM Report r left join r.user u WHERE r.totalCalBurned = :totalCalBurned AND u.height = :height"
```

Edit - change this:

```
@JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID", referencedColumnName = "USER_ID")
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Column(name = "USER_ID")
private Integer userId;
```

into:

```
@JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID")
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
private User user;
```

Comment: Is that still considered an implicit join? My understanding is that if I use the "join" key word then it's not considered an implicit join anymore.

Comment: @Pocky does that change anything? Besides i think `left join r.user u` can be omitted, but I'm not sure.

Comment: When I tried your example, I got the following errors: 
The collection-valued path 'r.User' cannot be resolved to a valid association field.
[94, 102] The state field path 'a.height' cannot be resolved to a valid type.

Comment: Did you define field `user` with relationship as in my answer?

Comment: The course I'm doing says to complete the exercise using only an implicit join here that's the only reason I care.

Comment: Yes I did it exactly like your answer.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I missed it:) Can you paste in the question the whole mapping?

Comment: Ok I have updated the post with the mapping. Those are the items I should be paying attention to regarding mapping right?

Comment: And the fields;)

Comment: Ok I added the fields too. Anything else that may be relevant?

Comment: Yeah so through talking with you I've come to realise that a lot of the code needed for mapping relations is missing so that's why joins aren't working. I will need to regenerate all of the object relational mapping. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Oh yeah now I have 15 reputation I can now upvote, upvoted!